# Extension of complex numbers to higher dimensions without losing commutativity and multiplicative inverse

Tags: complex-numbers

We have got the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and by trying to achieve algebraic closure, the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and finally the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ were developed. I know the fundamental theorem of algebra. For $\mathbb{C}$ you need two real numbers to define a complex number.

**Now my question is: Is there a nontrivial field that 
a) satisfies all properties of the complex numbers ( e.g. commutativity, multiplicative inverse,... --> these two rule out quaternions) and b) has 3 or more dimensions (i.e. is defined by 3 or more real numbers)?**

Comment: So you want a (commutative) field that contains $\mathbb{R}$ as a subfield and has dimension at least $3$ over $\mathbb{R}$? Do you want the field to have *finite* dimension over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @David: If finite is possible, yes.

Comment: The answer is no if you want the dimension to be finite. This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, although understanding the proof requires that you study abstract algebra. If infinite dimension is okay, then the set of all rational functions with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) answers the question, for example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28composition_algebras%29

Comment: Will Jagy's comments concern the answer to your question if you drop the requirement of commutativity, or even associativity (which is then replaced with a different condition).

Comment: @David: So the answer is no. Well, I have got another question: Are there some properties of the real numbers lost when you generalize to the complex numbers? In general, are there always some properties lost if you extend your field to achieve algebraic closure under some operation?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the more general question. The most important property that is lost when you go from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is that there is no way to order the complex numbers that really makes sense. (Technically, we say that there is no way to make $\mathbb{C}$ into an ordered field.) Compare this with the relation $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$, which satisfies nice properties such as $a + c < b + c$ whenever $a < b$, or $ac < bc$ whenever $a < b$ and $c > 0$.